# fsockopen doesn't work but is enabled

Tags: php, fsockopen

The following code does not work on my hosting, but the function fsockopen is enabled.  I tried the code on my localhost as well as on a friends website, and it worked just fine.

When I try it on my website, however, I get Connection timed out (110) error.

```
$fp = fsockopen($ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: There could be a firewall blocking the port.

Comment: It might be enabled, but do they have PHP set to allow URLs?

Comment: allow_url_fopen is enabled.